# Deploy frontend and backend app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, build, create-react-app

I tried to deploy my app to Heroku, but it is not working correctly. (using create-react-app for frontend and node.js in the backend)

My full app structure looks like this:

```
my-app
|
| ____ backend
| └── ...
| ____ frontend
└── ...
```

In the `package.json` I've added `--dest ../backend/public` to the build script:

```
scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build --dest ../backend/public",
},
```

Then I've ran these commands in the CMD on my `backend` folder:

```
> git init
> heroku create <my-app-name>
```

And this command on my `frontend` folder:

```
npm run build
```

Then, in the CMD on my `backend` folder:

```
> git add .
> git commit -m “<commit-messgae>”
> git push heroku master
```

When I go the my heroku app link I see the "Hello Backend!" message that I wrote in my `server.js` file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Backend!')
})
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hey has this been resolved?